Does anyone in Hong Kong issue personal checks, cashier's checks or international money orders that are cashable in the US?
I'm living in Hong Kong and have to pay a debt in an US institution.
The debtee would only accept the payment in personal check, cashier's check or international money order, and the payment has to be payable in US dollars and cashable in the US.
I only have Hong Kong bank accounts and don't have any US bank account. I've asked many financial institutions in Hong Kong whether they issue personal checks, cashier's checks or international money orders that are payable in US dollars and cashable in the US. They include local Hong Kong banks, Hong Kong branches of American banks such CitiBank and international transfer company such as Western Union.
All of they gave the following replies:

A personal check issued in Hong Kong cannot be cashed in the US.
They have never heard about the term "cashier's check". They do issue what is called a "cashier's order" in Hong Kong, but this cannot be cashed in the US.
The only form of check issued in Hong Kong that is cashable in the US is a "demand draft" (D/D), but the debtee does not accept the demand draft.
The most convenient way to make an international payment is the wire transfer, but the debtee also does not accept this.
They do not provide the service of international money order.

At this point I've almost lost hope, but still I may not exhaust all options, so I'm asking this question here:
Does anyone in Hong Kong issue personal checks, cashier's checks or international money orders that are cashable in the US?

Demand draft is what is called cashier's check in the US.

By "debtee", do mean the "US institution" itself, or the person/company having an account at the US institution? I find it implausible that a US bank is unwilling to recover the debt using Wire or ACH when the sender opts to pay the fee.

It means the "US institution" itself.
